# can I change a file to a folder

Tags: python, file, directory

I had a python script where I moved pictures to a folder called error. However I forgot to create the error folder. Now the images are moved to a file which created himself called error. The thing is that I cannot access it and display the images because it is a file not a folder. Have you any idea how I can recouver my pictures. Thanks in advance.

PS: Here is my python script maybe it might helpful

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(folder,filename),os.path.join(folder,'error'))
```

EDIT:

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
            a+=1
            wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(curiculum+'\\'+filename[0]+'.xlsx',read_only=True)
            ws=wb.active
            crn_counter=0
            for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_col=1,max_col=1,min_row=1,max_row=ws.max_row):
                for cell in rows:
                    if cell.value in filename:
                        crn=cell.value
                        lecture=ws.cell(column=2,row=cell.row).value
                        lecturer_temp=ws.cell(column=4,row=cell.row).value
                        break
                    else:
                        crn_counter+=1
            if crn_counter==ws.max_row:
                print('Excel dosyasinda CRN yok|',curiculum+'\\'+filename[0]+'.xlsx','|',filename)
            lecturer=finding_lecturer(lecturer_temp)
            if lecturer_temp=='***' or '--' in lecturer_temp or ',' in lecturer_temp:
                shutil.move(os.path.join(folder,filename),os.path.join(folder,'error'))
                print(filename,lecturer_temp,'MOVED TO ERROR')
                a-=1
                continue
           ..........
```

Answer (score 3):

As [shutil.move() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) state:

> If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be
> overwritten depending on [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) semantics.

Looking at [os.rename() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename):

> On Windows, if dst exists a FileExistsError is always raised.
>
> On Unix, if src is a file and dst is a directory or vice-versa, an
> IsADirectoryError or a NotADirectoryError will be raised respectively.
> If both are directories and dst is empty, dst will be silently
> replaced. If dst is a non-empty directory, an OSError is raised. **If
> both are files, dst it will be replaced silently if the user has
> permission.** The operation may fail on some Unix flavors if src and dst
> are on different filesystems. If successful, the renaming will be an
> atomic operation (this is a POSIX requirement).

If you didn't get any error I would guess you are on Linux and have overwritten files silently - one by one (i.e. each file overwitting the previous one) and at the moment `error` file is just the last file you moved.

Comment: I am on windows and no error occured but it can be the last file assuming from the file size. So there is no way I guess

Comment: if you are on windows, moving second file should raise `FileExistsError`, unless you have extra code (not shown here) to silence the exceptions. Are you sure all file have been moved?

Comment: no I have not but I guess it created an error file all the time and it was overwritten by the last time.

Comment: I added the code part and as you see there is no error handling and you can believe me I got no error, also if I had the error my pictures would not be overwritten and I would never have asked this question